# How to use moz-scrollber in linux ?

Tags: scrollbar, mozilla

How to use **moz-scrollbar** in linux.  it's work in mac but not working in linux.  anybuddy can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: for mozila firefox

Comment: Please add a minimal example of your code and add further information about used browser versions and OS versions.

Comment: but it is not working only in linux.